# How to get key depending on the value from HashMap

Tags: java

I have a `HashMap` in Java (named queue) which with `Integer` as the key and `List` of messages as a value related to each key. I want to visit all values of `List<messages>`, and compare each entry with the particular value that I feed it to the function `foo(Message m)`. If the entered value equal the value of HashMap, then get the key of this value and store it in a list. Here is my function:

```
public static List<Integer> getKey(Message m,MessageList m1) 
    {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Message>> entry:m1.queue.entrySet()) {
            if(m.equals(entry.getValue())) {
                l.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return l;
    }
```

But this function doesn't work. Is there any wrong?

Comment: Did you consider using a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

The value is of type `List<Message>` but you compare it to a single `Message`. Use [`List::contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public static List<Integer> getKey(Message m,MessageList m1)
{
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<Message>> entry:m1.queue.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getValue != null && entry.getValue().contains(m)) {
            l.add(entry.getKey());
        }
    }
    return l;
}
```